# PHP Ajax response gives data undefined when parsed by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

It wasn't giving the error just earlier today, but now with every fileupload I get

```
Unexpected number in JSON at position 161
```

I looked through the file upload JSON and understood there is an illegal 0 being passed with the file:

```
    {
    "ftype":"file",
    "meta":"prem-sal2.jpg",
    "fname":"screenshot1",
    "id":"392",
    "epn":"63",
    "action":"updategamefiles",
    "file":{
      "name":"prem-sal2.jpg",
      "type":"image/jpeg",
      "tmp_name":"/tmp/phpxPZNCL",
      "error":0,
      "size":968969
     }
    }
```

Here is the javascript that picks the file:

```
else if (fieldclass[1].indexOf("screenshot") >= 0) {
                ftype = 'file';
                document.getElementsByClassName(fname)[0].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML = 'Loading';
                meta = this.files[0].name;
                file = this.files[0];
                 if( file.type === "image/jpg" || file.type === "image/png"  || file.type === "image/gif" || file.type === "image/jpeg") {
                 extension = true;
                } 
            }
```

So how can I avoid getting that error:0 in file JSON?

Ah well, forgot to add Ajax request:

```
    if (extension === true) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('ftype', ftype);
    data.append('meta', meta);
    data.append('fname', fname);
    data.append('id', id);
    data.append('epn', epn);
    data.append('action', 'updategamefiles');
    var value = jQuery.ajax({
        data : data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        cache: false,
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {    

            if( data.response == 'SUCCESS' ){
                document.getElementsByClassName(data.fname)[0].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML = 'Success';
                document.getElementsByClassName(data.fname)[0].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + data.thumb +"')";

            } if( data.response == 'ERROR' ){
            document.getElementsByClassName(data.fname)[0].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].style.background = '#fdd2d2';
            document.getElementsByClassName(data.fname)[0].getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML = 'Error';

            }
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){    


            }
        })
        }
```

Comment: The error probably refers to the response that the server is sending, not the parameters you're sending. Check the server script, make sure it's not sending any output other than the JSON response.

Comment: @Barmar well response doesn't even have 161 character {"response":"SUCCESS","thumb":"link/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/8675d1300470dd0fc16d2427f58944db-267x200.jpg","fname":"screenshot1"}

Comment: I've found a number of web sites that say this is a Chrome bug, but they say it was fixed a couple of years ago.

Comment: Put the error message into google and you'll find them.

Comment: @Barmar Can't find any info, it seems my local search results are different, could you share a link?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/pXFpzqp1B0k/BEUj-aDbCQAJ https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/6yhzp8/uploading_a_thumbnail_and_it_saysunexpected_token/ https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/1028

Comment: Doesn't really look like my case. I pass this request to php backend, and there on php I saved both $_FILES and $_POST json and they are valid, all my php part of the code successfully works, success response is generated which is also valid, but in browser it says SyntaxError. I found some posts about possible UTF8 symbols validation, gonna dig that way for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to `die();` after echoing encoded json in response from php backend, without that I had extra data added to json that caused a problem.

Comment: This was what I said in my first comment: **make sure it's not sending any output other than the JSON response.**